# Okhttp websocket fails to connect over proxy

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

My mobile ISP has configured proxy.

This proxy redirects at some point with 200 OK.
Which is not by WS standard as it expects http status code 101.

When i curl same request it prints out correct http status code 101 and establishes connection.
Via OkHttp lib it fails to connect...
Any help?

Comment: Can you show the response headers etc from Curl?  Also for OkHttp would help.

Answer (score 1):

In OkHttp.Builder set proxy to Proxy.NO_PROXY